# What could be the potential dangers in this circuit?

Tags: ac, safety

What are the possible hazards with this circuit? There is a possibility that the D7 is not present and the point where D7 is connected would be touched.

R1 and R2 are 25 W resistors with voltage rating of 250 V. R4 would be some smaller SMD resistor. The switch is a 600 V solid-state relay.

As there is additional consumers added to the capacitor part, the AC may swing around, or simply charge the capacitor to 400 V and remain in steady state until the SSR closes. The SSR may be closed all the time as well.

Are there possibilities to burn out the resistors due to some transient events?

Are there possibilities for stray capacitance and inductance to play a role and swing the voltage high enough to break down one or more components as the one is breaking down?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this circuit? It's hard to believe it can't be done in a much safer and more efficient way.

Comment: The core goal is to bleed the capacitors when there is no live connection and indicate that there is high voltage present. But live AC also may be present. In theory this circuit is not supposed to be touched at all.

Comment: "R4 would be some smaller SMD resistor." And what happens if R4 opens???

Comment: I have to correct the 500 Ohm, which would be lower to remain within the power ratings of the component. I expect 60mA at maximum. It was meant to close the circuit if the diode is absent. If the diode is present, the current will flow through the diode. If the R4 opens and the diode is not present or open, there would be 400V on the node, which I want to avoid.

Comment: I think this question should be upvoted. While the idea is extremely dangerous, it is a valid question. Maybe someone else coming up with a similar idea will find this and realize what hazards they are setting up.

Comment: Is D7 a LED, and is the potential of "touching" due to possible mechanical damage to the LED? If so, you should definitely edit it into the question. You shouldn't be using a LED, but a mains-rated led-based indicator that is designed to be touch safe.

Comment: The reason I don't think it shouldn't be upvoted is because it is way to broad on safety. It doesn't allow an actual discussion on an electrical design safety aspect. The question is so fundamentally dangerous that the answers are not explaining how a fuse should be placed to protect a circuit or why galvanic isolation is required. It doesn't explain properly how to deal with transient or how to certify a system for safety. It tells him not to do it and why. If the question get more targeted to one aspect, it would be different.

Comment: add insulation until "possible to touch"  goes away.

Comment: If the 230VAC is a mains source, then one side of the 230VAC source is connected to Earth ground. That means your common is a floating danger.

Answer (score 5):

There is not much to discuss here. The "GND" symbol is at -370V peak during high line voltage condition of 240V+10%. Touching the point indicated is the same as touching the live mains conductor during the 2nd half-cycle of the mains.

> If the R4 opens and the diode is not present or open, there would be 400V on the node, which I want to avoid.

Nothing needs to open. **There's 400V on the node with everything normal!**

Here is the equivalent circuit during 2nd half of the mains cycle at 240V mains nominal voltage + 10% high line condition.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzoWeG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The triangular "ground" symbol is just a fancy way of choosing a "0V" reference point. It is **NOT** at earth potential just because we defined a node to be "ground"!

---

Also, R1 and R2 dissipate 10W each normally, and 40W during a single fault when either of them breaks down due to a transient.

In other words: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this is *not* the way to do it.

**Any touchable point must be galvanically isolated from mains**. That means there must be a sufficiently thick insulator present between the circuits that are touchable and the mains. Typically that's the insulator in a transformer. **Normal resistors are not galvanic insulation no matter their value**.

There are various models of human impedance, but we can say that 5kΩ may be a "rule of thumb" from hand to floor. 370V/5kΩ=75mA. With wet floor and wet hands, this will be over 100mA, and that's under "normal" conditions, i.e. assuming worst case expected line and human impedance. Under fault conditions it'll be worse that, and rather common mains transients can put 1A through the person unlucky enough to be messing with this circuit. Big oopsie.

You're touching mains via two diode drops. This is no different than sticking a metal rod into the Live terminal of an electrical socket and then grabbing it.

Comment: Please suggest him to simulate it and not build it! This device should not be built under any circumstance.

Comment: @Julien I took that suggestion out, imagining the spectacle of connecting a typical switchable scope probe to mains when it's accidentally set to 1:1. Even a 1:10 probe is not safe for mains use anyway. So yeah, you're right.

Comment: You could do it with a multimeter, and then try it, but I would argue that it is still to risky.

Comment: @Julien Yeah. How many people have 10W resistors rated for 400V working voltage? No way for most people to just take some parts and put it together right, even if they wouldn't touch anything. I shudder imagining someone trying to use typical carbon film 1/4W parts for this.

Answer (score 3):

Your "ground" is not at ground potential, but instead is just rectified mains half cycles.

You commonly see this setup in old valve TVs and radios, where the metal "chassis" is used for return currents.  I learnt very early on, that when working on these systems you always kept one hand in the pocket, to avoid one hand touching real ground and the other the chassis, with large currently through your body.

Contact at the point shown is extremely dangerous due to shock risk.

DON'T DO THIS.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, the potential danger in this circuit is death. Even without a failure, this design can deliver around 50mA to the user, which can be lethal. (10mA is considered lethal). This circuit is main referenced, therefore, if anyone was to touch it and any grounded element, he would get shocked with over 300V, which is very dangerous. We aren't even talking failure mode and your device could very well make you into a Darwin Award.

**For your specific questions**

Burning out the resistors is definitely a possibility. In case of overvoltage, they would most likely spark out and survive (which is even worst). They will burn out if any load is placed on D7 and surpass their power dissipation. 25W might seems like a lot, but, they will dissipate 25W with a current of only 150mA. You have nothing to prevent it to go that high. You should at least have a fuse inline.

For your question, is the capacitor dangerous. Well, 52uF isn't that much, but with that high of a voltage and no bleeding, I would say it's dangerous.

**Let's talk safety**

When doing main level appliance, there are IEC norm that you should be aware and comply to. Otherwise, you shouldn't design anything that goes on the main. This design is dangerous for so many reason. There are absolutely no safety in case of failure and if any component fails, the result could be catastrophic. For instance, what happens if D7 fails? Well, the current will all pass across R4 that might very well fail right after since it can't handle the load. Then, you have a 350V terminal that might be touched by any body. The 6.6k of resistance isn't sufficient to prevent the fatal level of 10mA.

Then, let's talk failure of the grid. If a lightening falls on the grid, this could expose thousands of volts to a potential user. We aren't even talking about a far fetch scenario...

This design is so dangerous that it shouldn't even be done in a controlled environment. **DON'T DO IT**

Comment: Rectified "230V" mains at high line is 370V worst case in absence of transients! That's at 240V maximum nominal voltage +10% high line condition. There's no "150V" in this circuit. Live swings +/-330V relative to Neutral at 230V+0%, but such circuits must be designed for the worst case: high end of the nominal voltage plus high line conditions. Depending on who you ask, a person is a 5kohm impedance, can be less if hands are moist etc. So, conservatively this will push 100mA through a person when everything is "normal". Oopsie daisy.

Comment: Oups! Even on the 120, this thing could kill someone. On the 240, it's crazy! I'll correct my numbers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the GND connection wrt earth ground for any potential contact with a human. Here GND is essentially at the same potential as the mains, hence not safe to touch.
Additionally, you may provide more details on the SSR used for SW1.
You typically need to provide reinforced isolation to protect humans against electric shock, and this circuit doesn't fulfill the requirements.

Regarding component damage, the circuit as shown should be fine, please be careful however on the exact choice of components (capacitor & diodes voltage rating). Some input protection (fuse+mov by example) might be a good addition as well.